# How to read text "LE 88" from the following HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, html-parsing, html-parser

How to read text "LE 88" from the following HTML using Javascript. the text LE is not constant, it keeps on changing. It neither contains ID's, nor class names.

```
 <body>
        <div id="Record">
            <div>
                <div>Grade A </div>
            </div>
            <div>19-04-2022
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>Subject H1
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>LE 88
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
```

Comment: Is the nesting of the tags always with the same structure?

Comment: If the structure inside `#Record` is always the same, use `document.querySelector('#Record :nth-child(3) :nth-child(2) div').textContent;`.

Comment: No. Structure keeps on changing

Comment: Then you're out of luck if you don't know the text you're searching for.

Comment: I just need text, irrespective of what characters it contains

Comment: There are three ways to search for an element from the DOM. Using an identifier (id, class or other attribute), using the content or using the DOM tree structure. If you can't use any of these, then you simply can't find an element you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the dom `div` and check for the children. In this case the `div` with text does not have any child. So use `children` and check for the `textContent`. If the matching text is found do  the required operation

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((curr) => {
  const child = curr.children;
  if (child.length === 0 && curr.textContent.trim() === 'Marks 88') {
    curr.textContent = 'Marks 88 changed'
  }

})
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Grade A </div>
  </div>
  <div>19-04-2022</div>
  <div>
    <div>Subject H1</div>
    <div>
      <div>Marks 88</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```